# SWIFT/XCODE Can't search in an array of String properly

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift

In the app i'm coding, i've got an array of String with contains 7 strings such as "Jh" or As" for Jack of Hearts or Ace of Spades.

I need to create functions to test the array and know if the player has a royal flush, a pair and so on.

Problem is, in my function isRoyalFlush, I want to know DIRECTLY if "Ah","Kh","Qh","Jh","10h" are presents in the 7elements array.

Here is what i'd like to do, and the error that XCODE is giving me :

```
    func isRoyalFlush(tab: Array<String>) -> String{
        if((tab.contains("Ah")) && (tab.contains("Kh")) && (tab.contains("Qh")) && (tab.contains("Jh")) && (tab.contains("10h"))){
            println("il y a Jh dans le tableau")
        }else{
            println("il n'y a pas Jh dans le tableau")
        }
    }
```

The error from XCODE is that array does not have a member called contains (OF COURSE...)

Thank You
Valentin B.

Comment: Why is your func called "is.." but returns a `String` instead of `Bool` and then it does not return anything at all?

Comment: Yep sorry it's that the name was given way back then !

Answer (score 2):

Try with `Contains` function,

```
func isRoyalFlush(tab: [String]) -> String{
    if (contains(tab, "Ah") && contains(tab, "Qh") && contains(tab, "Jh") && contains(tab, "10h")) {
        println("il y a Jh dans le tableau")
    }
    else {
        println("il n'y a pas Jh dans le tableau")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that should do it !

Answer (score 0):

It can be checked using the `contains` function. And your function is supposed to return a `string` as per your function definition.

```
func isRoyalFlush(tab: Array<String>) -> String{
    if((contains(tab,"Ah")) && (contains(tab,"Kh")) && (contains(tab,"Qh")) && (contains(tab,"Jh")) && (contains(tab,"10h"))){
        println("il y a Jh dans le tableau")
        return "il y a Jh dans le tableau" // added.
    }else{
        println("il n'y a pas Jh dans le tableau")
    }
    return "il n'y a pas Jh dans le tableau" // added.
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try `NSArray` instead of `Array`.

Comment: I thought about that but I never coded in Obj-C and i'm trying to code EVERYTHING in Swift, thanks anyway